# How to create rtl GridLayoutManager in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm creating a `recyclerView` in android project and i want to set a `gridLayout manager` in my `recyclerView` .

here is my Code :

```
workHourRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.market_hours_recycler);
workHourRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),4));
```

But `GridLayout` must be `'rtl direction'` anyone have idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to programmatically change the layout direction of the `RecycleView`

```
workHourRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.market_hours_recycler);
workHourRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),4));

//Programtically set the direction
workHourRecycler.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Comment: nice solution ! thanks

Comment: Dit it worked ??

Comment: Yeah , like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param context Current context, will be used to access resources.
 * @param spanCount The number of columns or rows in the grid
 * @param orientation Layout orientation. Should be {@link #HORIZONTAL} or {@link
 *                      #VERTICAL}.
 * @param reverseLayout When set to true, layouts from end to start.
 */ 



RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
rv_days.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
rv_days.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfRows, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
rvProductlist.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.